# Windows 8.1 64bit Kernel-Power 137 Error

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, kernel, standby

I'm at the moment encountering a problem with my windows 8.1 64bit Version. Some days ago I realised that it takes longer than usual to start the computer or wake it up, in fact, the computer seems to be running but the display keeps telling me that it has no signal. After some time (approx. 1min) I finally am able to use it. Usually I'm restarting my computer once a week and standby every evening.
After a look in the Event log, I found that there is in this cases a Kernel-Power Error 137 with the caption: 

`"The system firmware has changed the processors memory type range registers MTRRs across a sleep state transition S5"`
The error was listed the first time on March 18th at 22:20. I own the computer since early november 2014. After that I checked my installed programms and saw, that I installed Drivers for my Epson Printer on the same day. So I looked up for potential updates but there were none. 
So my Queston is how can I fix the problem? I ran Malwarebytes and am using Avast as AV.I also ran the troubleshooting and it found no errors. 
My System is Windows 8.1 64bit, AMD Radeon R9 270, AMD FX 8300 8core, 8 GB Ram, 128 GB SSD, 1TB HDD.

<s>**EDIT:** It seems like there is only this error after turning off the power supplie. I'm usually doing that with a toggle switch...</s>

**Edit2:** Also happening when computer has power supplie, The printer drivers are uninstalled, still the same problem.

**Edit3:** It only happens when I turn the computer on Standby. Not if I restart or shutdown the computer.

**Edit4:** I reinstalled the OS and everything else and after around a week without a problem (all programms installed since the first day) i now get the kernel errors again. Gladly thr computer is still fast. Is the error maybe caused by a windows update?

Comment: Try in [this article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/the-system-firmware-has-changed-the-processors/c1fd88e3-3d23-43c7-a640-06750c82abd5) the 3rd method and let us know.

Comment: Already tried that method, it isn't working. :(